# Drawing LineStrings d3

Tags: d3.js, maps

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around drawing GeoJSON LineStrings to a map with d3. I'm using Leaflet (per Mike Bostock's example), and my page loads without error. However, nothing draws to my map.

Any help would be appreciated!

Snippet of my data:

```
{"type": "LineString", "coordinates":[[-74.12706, 40.734680000000004],...]}
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
/* Load the map */
var map = new L.Map("map", {center: [40.7127, -74.0059], zoom: 10})
    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer(URL_TO_MY_TILES));

function makemap(error, data){
    var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

    var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);


    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(data.coordinates)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("d","path")
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem, in case anyone else runs into it later on.

My GeoJSON was not formatted correctly, despite checking out when testing it on a GeoJSON Lint website. Always good to read your specs!!